# Simplifying a Boolean algebra equation

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have a boolean algebra equation that i'm not able to simplify fully.

\begin{align}
&(c+ab)(d+b(a+c))\\
&(c+ab)(d+ba+bc)\\
&cd+ abc + bc^2+abd+a^2 b^2 + ab^2 c\\
&\text{using boolean laws $x^2=x$ and $x+x=x$}\\
&cd + bc + abd + ab + (abc +  abc)\\
&cd + bc + abd + ab + abc
\end{align}
And now I get stuck. Mathematica simplifies this to $ac+bc+bd$, but I just don't see how.

Comment: This is a Boolean ring, not algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have typed this into Mathematica incorrectly. Here's the solution:

\begin{align*}
(c+ab)(d+b(a+c)) & =(c+ab)(d+ab+bc))\\
 & =cd+abc+bc+abd+ab+abc\\
 & =cd+abc+bc+abd+ab\\
 & =cd+bc+ab(c+d+1)\\
 & =cd+bc+ab
\end{align*}

Here's [Wolfram Alpha computing the same thing](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(c%20or%20(a%20and%20b))%20and%20(d%20or%20(b%20and%20(a%20or%20c)))) (DNF).

Comment: Weird that it's different answer than what my Mathematica computes. `BooleanMinimize[(C && (A || 
       B)) || (D && (B || (A && C)))] // TraditionalForm` yields $(A \wedge C) \vee (B\wedge C)\vee(B\wedge D)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have backwards the AND's and the OR's entered in Mathematica, you should use:

BooleanMinimize[(C || (A && B)) && (D || (B && (A || C)))

|| = AND (*)

&& = OR (+)